# Remove something added by a particular event - c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, checkbox, combobox, listbox

I have a piece of code that will add the selected item of a combobox to a listbox when a checkbox is checked. I would like to remove that selected item to be removed from the listbox when the checkbox is unchecked.

My problem is I cant simply repeat the code for removal to be the same as add because the combobox selection will different or empty when unchecked.

This is how it currently looks:

```
private void CBwasher_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
     {
          listBox2.Items.Add(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
     }
     if (checkBox1.Checked == false)
     {
         listBox2.Items.Remove(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
     }
```

So I need a way of removing whatever was added by that check change instead of removing the selected index of the combobox. Please consider that there may be multiple lines in the listbox added by multiple different checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to store the added item and remove it.

```
private object addedItem;
private void CBwasher_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (checkBox1.Checked)
     {
          addedItem = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
          listBox2.Items.Add(addedItem);
     }
     else
     {
         listBox2.Items.Remove(addedItem);
     }
}
```

You may also need to check `SelectedItem` is null before adding/removing the item.

Comment: And by the way you could write if(checkBox1.Checked){....} without "== true" , just saying :)

Comment: @Ashur451 Sigh. How I missed it :? Thanks

Comment: Where you write addedItem, do you mean to actually write added item into the code or whatever the added item is because im getting "the type or namespace "addedItem" could not be found"

Comment: I missed you line at the top about private object, i now understand and have managed what i wanted but it only seems to work for 1 checkbox, if i use more than 1 it doesnt

Comment: @JoeGoddard What do you mean by more than one checkbox? How do you use it?

Comment: i figured it out, for every checkbox i entered i wanted to add its combobox value into the list. I solved this by adding an individual AddedItem for each checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on the part where you said there might be multiple different checkboxes,
you need to store one item per checkbox.

You can write your own child class of the checbox control to add this feature, or simply use the Tag property.
You can also indicate which checkbox is linked to which combobox in the same way. Either child class or use the Tag property.

In my example, I'll assume you've referenced the combobox from the checkbox using the Tag property.
You can do it manually like this

```
checkBox1.Tag = comboBox1;
```

or hopefully you can automate it if you are generating these on the fly.

Here is the general idea of how the checkbox event should look.
The event is is utilising the sender argument, which means you should hook up all your checkboxes CheckedChanged events to this one handler. No need to create separate handlers for each.

```
private void CBwasher_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var checkBox = (CheckBox)sender;
     var comboBox = (ComboBox)checkBox.Tag;
     if (checkBox.Checked && comboBox.SelectedItem != null)
     {
          listBox2.Items.Add(comboBox.SelectedItem);
          comboBox.Tag = comboBox.SelectedItem;
     }
     if (!checkBox.Checked && comboBox.Tag != null)
     {
         listBox2.Items.Remove(comboBox.Tag);
     }
}
```